# Fetching cyrillic characters from TMemo

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I am developing an application using Lazarus and I have to get the characters of a text that the user has entered in a TMemo component. I am using the following code to fetch the characters one by one (here mmText is the name of the TMemo component):

```
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Line: String;
  Symbol: Char;
begin
  for I := 0 to mmText.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    Line := mmText.Lines[I];

    for J := 1 to Length(Line) do
    begin
      Symbol := Line[J];
      ShowMessage(Symbol); //this line is for debugging purposes 
      ...
```

When latin characters are entered in the TMemo component, popup messages with each letter appear but when the cycle reaches a cyrillic character there is nothing in the popup message box.

Could you give me advice what I should do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: What lazarus version are you using? Have you read [this](http://wiki.freepascal.org/LCL_Unicode_Support)?

Comment: Do you know how your text is encoded?

Comment: I am using Lazarus version 1.4.0. Using the UTF8ToAnsi  and AnsiToUTF8 functions doesn't help.

Comment: Trying functions at random isn't productive. Why don't you try to understand how your text is encoded?

Comment: The problem is that a cyrillic symbol is stored as 2 bytes but the line "Symbol := Line[J]" reads only 1 byte. The question is how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, the answer is here:

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=29146.msg183536#msg183536

Comment: Its help for me! Thanks.